# Could not find matching constructor for: DomainObjectName(java.lang.String)

Tags: grails

I am using command object and I have used a domain object inside my command object as given below.

```
class JobCommand {
  List<Country> countries
  String name
  String age
  .....
}
```

Country Domain is as follows:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes="id")
class Country{
String id
String name
Date createDate
......
}
```

I am accessing this jobCommand object from my JobController to and also in my gsp page to set the value in my Country field. 
I have a search field named Country in my gsp page and it has options of Countries like, USA, India, Iran etc.

```
 <g:select name="countries" id="country" 
        from="${Country.findAll()}"
        value="${jobCommand ?.countries}"
        multiple="true" 
        optionKey="id"
        optionValue="name"
 />
```

When I select multiple Countries, and click search button, I get the exception "Could not find matching constructor for: package.Country(java.lang.String)".

Comment: Why is the g:select tag named *country* yet the command object property is named *countries*?

Comment: Hi Rosa, thank you for the comment. Actually you were correct. It was my typing mistake. g:select tag name is "countries" only. I have corrected the question.

Comment: Obviously that constructor is missing. But which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: Data is displayed in my view and there is no error log in the console. So, I am not able to say which line of code is throwing the exception. I believe it should be the Country constructor since the message shows(Could not find matching constructor for: package.Country(java.lang.String)) .  Only I can see here is the above mentioned message in my view. Do we need to mention constructor explicitly in grails?

Comment: The exception is not in the constructor because that constructor doesn't exist. The exception is coming from the code that's attempting to call the constructor. Take a second look at not only the console but also the exception rendered in the view. That stack trace contains important information. In Grails unexpected things can happen when you change the default id; like how you replaced it with a `String` in `Country`.

Comment: Thank you Rosa for your answer. I really appreciate it. The naming convention is confusing me a lot. I will check the exception in the view and let you know the scenario. Could you please look at another problem too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403072/params-values-are-always-null-in-controller-on-clicking-gactionsubmit-button

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to Bind Params to Command object.
1. Use bindData (http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Controllers/bindData.html)
2. To write our own Converters. I had the same issue and I wrote my own  converters.

Steps to write own converter : 
create converter class with below methods:

```
boolean canConvert(value) {
        value instanceof String
    }

    def convert(value) {
        //your logic
    }

    Class<?> getTargetType() {
        //your type
    }
```

Register your converter in resources.groovy inside bean{}