# params values are always null in controller on clicking <g:actionSubmit> button

Tags: grails, gsp

In my application, I have search button and based on the search criteria, I have to search data. I have used few hidden variables to store data.

My .gsp page looks like this:

```
<g:form id="job" name="job" method="POST">
<div>
<input type="hidden" id="country" name="country" value="${country}"/>
<input type="hidden" id="paginationFlag" name="paginationFlag" value="${paginationFlag}"/>
<!-- There are other components like text field, select box etc --> 
<g:actionSubmit id="Search" value="Search" formmethod="post"    action="findJob"/>
</div>
</g:form>
```

My respective controller method looks like this:

```
def  findJob(){
def country
def paginationFlag

if(params?.country){
  country = params?.country
}else{
  country = 'USA'
}

if(params?.paginationFlag){
 paginationFlag = params?.paginationFlag
}else{
 paginationFlag = 'false'
}

withFormat{
 html{
  List<Applicant> searchList //get data from database.
  // other business logic
    render(view : "jobList",model:[paginationFlag: paginationFlag, country:country])
}

json{
    // some business logic
    def candidateList // value for this candidateList is acquired from database
    def json = ['jsn': candidateList]
    render json as JSON
  }
}
```

When I click search button and debug the code, first my control goes to controller-> findJob() method and executes the code inside html part.
Secondly, it goes to the gsp page (view page) and sets value.Third, it again goes to the controller and executes the code inside json part.

On the first entry to the controller, the value of paginationFlag and country in param are both null. So it will set the value 'false' and 'USA' respectively. But when control goes to controller again for the second time, again the value of param.paginationFlag and params.country are null. Should not they have the assigned values?

Why is it so? What should I do go get the value of country and paginationFlag in params on the second time? Can any one explain me ? Thank you very much for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're using a regular HTML `input` tag rather than a Grails `g:hiddenField` tag. Try this:

```
<g:form id="job" name="job" method="POST">
    <div>
    <g:hiddenField name="country" value="${country}"/>
    <g:hiddenField name="paginationFlag" value="${paginationFlag}"/>
    <!-- There are other components like text field, select box etc --> 
    <g:actionSubmit id="Search" value="Search" formmethod="post"    action="findJob"/>
    </div>
</g:form>
```

## Tip

You can also simply the params assignment:

```
def country = params.country ?: 'USA'
def paginationFlag = params.paginationFlag ?: 'false'
```

I can't tell where the `paginationFlag` comes from, but know that a `boolean` is valid.

Comment: Thank you very much Rosa for the answer. And also thanks for the tips. Since I am new to groovy, these kinds of tips helps me a lot. I tried using <g:hiddenField> as well. Again same thing is happening to me. When my control goes to the controller method second time (I think it's a ajax call second time), the params .country and params.pagination is again null.

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure the `jobList` view is getting the `country` and `paginationFlag` from the controller. And then make sure the second call is providing the params.

Comment: I checked it. When control goes to the view, I am able to get value for jobList and paginationFlag. But when debug goes to controller again for the json part (second time), that time I am getting these values as null. I found one option that is using jobList and paginationFlag as global variable in the controller. But I think this might cause the problem later.